# unable to add one more layout in mvc giving error -The "RenderBody" method has not been called for layout page "~/Views/Shared/MyLayout.cshtml"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, layout, view

i have added created and added one layout to view. its giving error while rendering that view.

> The "RenderBody" method has not been called for layout page "~/Views/Shared/MyLayout.cshtml".

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult MyPage()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "My Page.";
    return View();
}
```

**View**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MyPage";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/MyLayout.cshtml";
}
<h2>MyPage</h2>
```

**Layout**

```
@{
    Layout = null;
} 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>MyLayout</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        <h1>Its My Layout Page....</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The error message is self explanatory. You need to add `@RenderBody()` to the layout.

Comment: thanks i got it....sorry im new in mvc

Comment: i have one doubt. where exactly i have to  put the @RenderBody().starting of the div or ending of the div or anywhere in the div or anywhere in the body

Comment: Anywhere you want. It acts as a placeholder to define where in the layout you want the html generated by the view to be placed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout should be something like the below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>MyLayout</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        <h1>Its My Layout Page....</h1>
    </div>
   <div id="content">
       @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

So in your layout you set the **CSS** styles you want to use which your other pages can inherit from.
You can render the body of your other pages anywhere in the layout like I've done with the below

```
<div id="content">
...
</div>
```